# Numpy source directory ImportError on raspberry pi

Tags: python, numpy

I get the following error every time  when trying to run a simple graph program on a raspberry pi 4 32 bit bullseye os.

```
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter
```